# .jcall error when using ReporteRs R

Tags: java, r, reporters

I have no issues using the ReporteRs package when I'm at work, but at home I'm having problems. If I try to use the sample code from the package:

```
require(rJava)
require(ReporteRs)
require( ggplot2 )
.jinit()
doc = docx( title = 'My document' )
doc = addTitle( doc , 'First 5 lines of iris', level = 1)
doc = addFlexTable( doc , vanilla.table(iris[1:5, ]) )
doc = addTitle( doc , 'ggplot2 example', level = 1)
myggplot = qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, size = Petal.Width )
doc = addPlot( doc = doc , fun = print, x = myggplot )
doc = addTitle( doc , 'Text example', level = 1)
doc = addParagraph( doc, 'My tailor is rich.', stylename = 'Normal')
filename <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx") # the document to produce
writeDoc( doc, filename )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(doc$obj, "[S", "getStyleNames") : 
  java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

I have no experience with java, so I'm not really sure how to trouble shoot this. If it's helpful, doc$obj returns this:
"Java-Object{org.lysis.reporters.docs.docx4R@2353354a}"

Comment: You should not call `.jinit()`... If possible, move to package `officer`. There is no java dependancy.

Comment: Thank you David for your response and this useful package. Is there a way to change the author and last editor of a document so that it shows my name rather than yours?

Comment: Also, what options are their for customizing the look of a table? ReporteRs has considerable capacity for manipulating tables.

Comment: Q1: not yet but soon. Q2: have a look at package flextable